# Animate frame and layout change of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to create an effect where I change the layout of my UICollectionView while changing the frame size

Initially the collectionView layout presents a "thumbnail" gallery style full screen.

After resizing the frame to a thin strip - I would like to present a "film strip" style layout

both layouts independently work fine and as expected.

I tried code similar to this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.collectionview.frame = newFrame; // animate the frame size


                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:filmstriplayout animated:YES];    // now set the new layout
                     }];
```

But it is looking very choppy and not resizing as expected.

Is there a way where I could change the collectionview layout and the frame size simultaneously while animating the change?

Comment: Did you ever get a good solution? `performBatchUpdates:withCompletion:` is good, but doesn't help with combining an animated `frame` or `contentOffset` change. I want to get this for smoothly animating zoom bounce back where my layout and `contentOffset` dependent on zoom.

Comment: @Benjohn did *you* find a good solution? Just came across the same thing and the existing answers aren't ideal...

Comment: @aheze Sorry, I don’t know — it’s further back than I can remember now :-/

Answer (score 21):

I don't have a specific answer, but a few suggestions to consider.

`UICollectionView` doesn't always handle switching layout instances gracefully. Here is a good [discussion of the problem and some workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780138/dynamically-setting-layout-on-uicollectionview-causes-inexplicable-contentoffset).

But what I’ve actually done in practice that worked for me was to implement both layouts in a single layout object that knows how to toggle between layout modes. I found that switching layout modes in a batch update block was less problematic than using `setCollectionViewLayout` with two different layout instances:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    MyLayout *layout = (MyLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    layout.mode = otherLayoutMode;
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: What do you use `performBatchUpdates:`?

Comment: Setting a new instance during an update, seriously?. It will eventually crash your app.

Answer (score 20):

First set the grid item size like `gridItemSize = CGSizeMake(98, 98);` then perform the batch action of UICollectionView. The items in collection view change their sizes with animation. :)

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return CGSizeMake(gridItemSize.width, gridItemSize.height);
}

[self.collectionview performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionview.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    [self.collectionview setCollectionViewLayout:self.collectionview.collectionViewLayout animated:YES];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {    
}];
```

Comment: This is handy stuff, but **what about that animated frame change** occurring at the same time? Equivalently, I think, a `contentOffset` change? I also need both to happen at once.

Comment: In my use case, my flowLayout needs to be different when it's being scrolled and when it's static. What I do is: (1st) set a flag in the layout and use the code above to invalidate the layout; (2nd) scrollToIndexPath animated using the default collectionViewMethod; (3rd) reset the layout flag and use the above code again to animate it back to the original state. I couldn't achieve the desired results by animating them at the same time, so I just queued the animations.

Comment: `[self.collectionview.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];` is odd here, it leads to bugs in animation.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the simple trick whenever you are updating the CollectionView use this:

```
[self.collectionView removeFromSuperview]; //First remove the Collection View

//Relocate the view with layouts
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10;

 self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width,100) collectionViewLayout:layout];
[self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
[self.collectionView reloadData];

[self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
```